# ～は止めた方がいい　or ～を止めた方がいい

Tags: grammar

I really don't get why I usually see that people use は instead of を in this case.
The reason why I do not understand it is this sentence:

> ～を選んだ方がいい

I have seen people using this sentence without は.
Then, my question is:
Why , in this specific case, with the verb 選ぶ people use を but with 止める people use は?

Comment: What verb were you thinking of with 止める, since you feel that the specific verb is important? 止める could be とめる or やめる.

Answer (score 1):

は replaces を (or が, or follows after other particles) when the information *after* the は is *more important* (or "new to the listener") than the information before it. That is clearly the case with 〜止めた方がいい - the speaker and the listener are both familiar with whatever is being referred to before that point; it's the "you'd better quit that!" part that is the main purpose of the sentence, so は is used to emphasize that latter part of the sentence.

Meanwhile, 〜を選んだ方がいい is more neutral in terms of "which side of the sentence is important", and using は would imply that the thing being chosen is already understood as the topic of conversation - it's the fact of choosing it that is new - and that's just not a common scenario.

I frequently like to consider, when choosing whether or not "to は", what kind of question the sentence could be in answer to, as that dictates whether or not は is appropriate. If it could answer a question where a question word occurs in the part of the sentence before the particle, then you don't use は, otherwise you probably should.

> これは何ですか？ →　これはペンです
>
> だれがいますか？ →　山田さんがいます
>
> これは、どうしよう？　→　それは[止]{や}めた方がいいよ
>
> どの道を選んだ方がいい？　→　右の道を選んだ方がいい

Comment: しようよ？ is never a question.

Comment: @user4092 AIUI the よ is used to mean something like "...is what I wanna know, yeah?" in such cases. Same with 「どこへ行こうよ」

Comment: alternatively, adding a flavor of exasperation

Comment: Let me edit your examples to sound more natural.  「よ」をつけて exasperation を表すなら、「どうするんだよ！？」「どうすんだよ！？」「どうすんのよ！？」「どこ行くんだよ！？」「どこ行くのよ！？」とかね・・